# Correct default Google Chrome base search engine URL

Tags: google-chrome

When searching using Google Chrome the search will not load.

I have deleted Google chrome and reinstalled several  times, still the same problem.

I have deleted Google chrome and gone into the registry and deleted chrome, reinstalled chrome, still the same problem.

When entering Google Chrome settings and clicking manage search engines the Google search engine is shown as

```
(google:baseURL)search?q=%s&(googleRLZ)(go...
```

How do I delete this and reinstate the correct Google search engine?

Answer (score 0):

Exit Chrome. Head to `%localappdata%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\` and look for a file called `Preferences`. Rename/delete/move the file elsewhere.

Launch Chrome, Chrome will recreate the file & the base search URL should be fixed